# Gremlin - How to filter while converting property to Integer?

Tags: groovy, gremlin, rexster

I have the following segment of gremlin code:

```
vert.as('x').
both.or(
  _().has("time").filter{ _()["time"] > startTime.toInteger() },
  _().has("isRead"), _().has("isWrite")).dedup{}.gather.scatter.
store(y).loop('x'){c++ < limit.toInteger()}.iterate();
```

I would think that this would filter the items out whose time attribute value resolve to be greater than startTime. But this isn't the case. How do I get the time of the current object in the pipeline in order to compare it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the answer really fast. I should have known, being as I've read basically all the gremlin documentation... :/

```
vert.as('x').
both.or(
  _().has("time").filter{ it.time > startTime.toInteger() },
  _().has("isRead"), _().has("isWrite")).dedup{}.gather.scatter.
store(y).loop('x'){c++ < limit.toInteger()}.iterate();
```

Comment: Note that `it.time` is really slow.  For production use, do `it.getProperty('time')`.